# Python profiling: time spent on each line of function

Tags: python, numpy, workflow, profile

I have been studying examples from the [profile documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)  and I have come to the workflow when I run

```
import cProfile as profile
import pstats

pr = profile.Profile()
pr.runcall(myFunc, args, kwargs)

st = pstats.Stats(pr)
st.print_stats() # and other methods like print_callees, print_callers, etc.
```

This gives me some general stats of the number of calls made and so on. Mind you, it is rather cryptic: I heaviliy use `numpy` inside `myFunc` (like `numpy.sum`, `*` and the like) but I cannot find those calls in the stats object. What I would like to see is the time spent on each line of the source code of function `myFunc`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good package for that on PyPI - [`line_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/)